# where is FLAG_hard_abort in v8 sources

Tags: v8

GitHub search reveals only 2 occurances: [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/search?q=FLAG_hard_abort&ref=cmdform)

(Am I using GitHub search wrong?)

Where is `FLAG_hard_abort` defined in the V8 source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it [here (flag-definitions.h)](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/flag-definitions.h#468):

```
DEFINE_bool(hard_abort, true, "abort by crashing")
```